# How can I display a web page as my Gnome screensaver?

Tags: gnome, screensaver

We'd like to change our screensavers to show the current status of our service at a glance. We already have a page that shows uptime, build status, and more as large red and green squares, and that page refreshes automatically.

We're all running Gnome. How can we make that page our screensaver?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try [cutycap](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/), a webkit based 'www-snapshoter':

> CutyCapt is a small cross-platform command-line utility to capture WebKit's rendering of a web page into a variety of vector and bitmap formats, including SVG, PDF, PS, PNG, JPEG, TIFF, GIF, and BMP. See IECapt for a similar tool based on Internet Explorer.

then setup your screensaver application to pick up the snapshotted website pictures.

Comment: Hmmm... This is good, but I'd like a smoother solutionn. This requires a cron job, and a screensaver that's okay with rotating through a single image and doesn't cache. Hmm.

Answer (score 2):

hmm ... maybe try the merger of what you both said ...

cron as "nobody" (or equivalent) every minute to run cutycapt into imagedir/`date +nagios-%y-%m-%d_%T.jpg` with auto-cleanup =

... * * * * * dir="/usr/share/admin/ScreenSaverDir" && a=`date +$dir/nagios-%y-%m-%d_%T.png` && CutyCapt --url=http://nagios.MyDomain.com/ --out=$a && && b=`ls -1tr $dir | tail -1` && rm `ls -1  $dir | egrep -v $b`

so the most recent image is going to be the *only* thing in that directory but it will have a unique-to-the-second filename, guaranteeing that it will not be cached by the screensaver